# I've got a mySQL database full of <a> tags but the links are not working when echo'ing

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
$mydb = new wpdb('xxxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx','localhost');
$max_id = $mydb->get_results("SELECT MAX(id) FROM `links1`");
$row_id = ceil((mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax()) * intval($max_id[0]->{"MAX(id)"}));
$row_pre = $mydb->get_results("SELECT link FROM `links1` WHERE id=" . $row_id);
$row = $row_pre[0]->link;
```

my rows contain anchor tags like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

But when this code runs, it only displays this in the browser:

```
 google
```

Link does not work. Why?

=========

Here's the code that's outputting the code:

```
<?php require_once('add.php'); ?>
            <p><?php echo $row; ?></p>
```

=========
I've even tried doing this for testing purposes:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($row);
```

And it displays the raw anchor tags! Like this in the browser:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++

EDIT!!!!!

I looked at the outputted html in the browser through Chrome's dev tools and the slashes are missing in the link!!! WHY?

Comment: displays that in the browser, or in the source code?

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you're using to put the data out?

Comment: any reason why the database contain the link format? normally your database should have the url and then formatted in as you like in your code.

Comment: I think I found your problem, your link is already well formed as html code, it means that you just echo at as raw with out `->link`. So try `->link`, it will automatically comes up as link. I have just test it, if it works for you let me know. I have test it on firefox/internet exp/chrome

Comment: I tried removing '->link' and I get this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in "...filepath..." on line 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was the fact that the column being fetched contained the ENTIRE anchor link. Once we changed the database to contain the URL in one column, and the Link Name in another column, it worked!

Not sure why... Maybe it's a security issue to pull an entire anchor link from a column.

Answer (score 0):

Put **http://** before google.com:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

Updated Query:

While selecting the link you can just concat the http:// to your link like below:

```
SELECT concat('http://',link) as link FROM `links1` WHERE id=" . $row_id
```